# How does Windows Run registry key search for executable

Tags: windows-registry

Example for the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run, I have the executable name set as hello.exe instead of its full path. How does Windows search for the executable, is there a particular order.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It will iterate through the `%path%` variables, then if it can't find it, return an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows will assume that the `.exe` is located in a directory as specified in your Environment Variables; specifically your `%path%`
variable.

[image]

If you type `path` into a command prompt, a semi-colon list of paths will be returned. Or, click 'Edit' whilst Path is highlighted in the list of environment variables, to be presented with an editable list.